# Finding distance between every two strings that are values in a dictionary and printing them with corresponding key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the function that calculates the distance between two strings but I have to write a function that finds distance of two strings that are the values in a dictionary. Each value has to find distance between itself, the next value, and the value after that and so on. The function that calculates the distance is:

```
def computeDistance(seq1,seq2):

    num_difference = 0.0

    m=0.0

    for i in range(0,10):

        if seq1[i] != seq2[i]:

        num_difference += 1

        m=num_difference/(len(seq1))

return m
```

the input will be something like

```
S = {'S01'='agcagagtta','S1111'='ccgccctagt','S001'='cgtgatgcat'}
```

the output should be like:

```
S01 - S1111 : 1.0

S01 - S001 : 0.8

S1111 - S001 : 0.8
```

Comment: Can you reformat your code, the indentation for the for loop and if statement aren't right. Also can you clarify what you mean by distance

Comment: by distance i meant the number of changes between two strings, how different they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
S = {'S01':'agcagagtta','S1111':'ccgccctagt','S001':'cgtgatgcat'}
keys = []
for k1, v1 in S.iteritems():
    d = 0
    lv1 = len(v1)
    for k2, v2 in S.iteritems():
        if k1 != k2 and k2 not in keys:
            #print [v1[e]!=v2[e] for e in range(lv1)],([v1[e]!=v2[e] for e in range(lv1)].count(True)), lv1
            d = [v1[e]!=v2[e] for e in range(lv1)].count(True)/float(lv1)
            print "%s - %s: %s" % (k1,k2,d)
    keys.append(k1)
```